# INSERT INTO with SELECT and exterior value

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert

I'm trying to copy a line from a table to another table. But the second table have to received two additional parameters (hour and autor) which are not in the first table.

Here is my try:

```sql
INSERT INTO Individus_corbeille
  (
    SELECT * 
    FROM Individus 
    WHERE ID_individu='706782','NOW()','autor'
  )
```

But it absolutely doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO Individus_corbeille 
SELECT *, NOW(), 'autor'
FROM Individus 
WHERE ID_individu='706782'
```

But you should actually also name the columns you insert into and the ones you select like this

```
INSERT INTO Individus_corbeille (col1, col2, col3, col4)
SELECT col1, col2, NOW(), 'autor'
FROM Individus 
WHERE ID_individu='706782'
```

Comment: Rather `NOW()` not `'NOW()'`. Also without specyfing columns in table and select it may be dangerous

Comment: @lad2025 . . . That might seem logical, but the OP explicitly has `now()` in quotes.